# nodejs OOP . linking classes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js I am just migrating over from java.

In my node.js REST API, car booking application, I have create a BookingSchema and in that I want to link my Carschema. So the booking object links to the carobject.

Can anyone guide me how to do it? or is it wrong way of doing things?

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var BookingSchema = new Schema({
    UserCarSchema: {   //how to do THIS?
        type: String,
        required: 'Kindly enter car details'
    },
    booking_date: {
        type: Date,
        required: 'Please enter date'
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Booking', BookingSchema);
```

My usercar is as below:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserCarSchema = new Schema({
    model: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Kindly enter car model'
    },
    contact_number: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Please enter contact number'
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserCar', UserCarSchema);
```

Comment: Try it without the 'new' keyword before Schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to create a relationship between the two schemas. in the user model you can add something like.

```
userSchema.virtual('booking', {
    ref: 'Booking',
    localField: '_id',
   foreignField: 'bookee'
});
```

then as part of your booking model build your relationship with the user as an object on the model like this.

```
bookee:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'UserCar'
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
var BookingSchema = new Schema({
    car: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserCar'},
    booking_date: {
        type: Date,
        required: 'Please enter date'
    }
});
```

This makes a property on `Booking` named `car`, which will hold the ID of a `UserCar`.

When retrieving with a query then you can do this:

```
BookingModel.findOne({}).populate('car').exec().then(booking => {
  console.log(booking);
});
```

By adding `populate('car')`, Mongoose will replace the `car` property with the the actual `UserCar` object the ID points to.

[Here is the documentation for populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Thanks..that works. instead of referencing to UserCar object id, how to reference to  UserCar.contact_number ?